# Moving average in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, moving-average

I would like to compute a moving average over data in a SQLite table. I found several method in MySQL, but couldn't find an efficient one in SQLite.

In SQL, I think something like this should do it (however, I was not able to try it...) :

```
SELECT date, value, 
avg(value) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND 3 FOLLOWING) as MovingAverageWindow7
FROM t ORDER BY date;
```

However, I see two drawbacks :

- This does not seems to work on sqlite
- If data are not continuous for few dates on preceding/following rows, it computes a moving average on a window which is wider than what I actually want since it is only based on the number of surrounding rows. Thus, a date condition should be added

Indeed, I would like it to compute the average of 'value' at each date, over +/-3 days (weekly moving average) or +/-15 days (monthly moving average)

Here is an example data set :

```
CREATE TABLE t ( date DATE, value INTEGER );

INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-02-01', 8);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-02-02', 2);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-02-05', 5);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-02-06', 4);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-02-07', 1);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-02-10', 6);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-02-11', 0);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-02-12', 2);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-02-13', 1);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-02-14', 3);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-02-15', 11);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-02-18', 4);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-02-20', 1);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-02-21', 5);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-02-28', 10);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-03-02', 6);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-03-03', 7);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-03-04', 3);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-03-08', 5);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-03-09', 6);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-03-15', 1);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-03-16', 3);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-03-25', 5);
INSERT INTO t (date, value) VALUES ('2018-03-31', 1);
```

Comment: These _window functions_ (`... OVER (...)`) maybe didn't work because they were introduced in SQLite 3.25. My version (as it comes with Ubuntu 18.04) is 3.22, so it didn't work for me either. :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Window functions were added in version 3.25.0 (2018-09-15). With the RANGE frame type added in version 3.28.0 (2019-04-16), you can now do:

```
SELECT date, value, 
avg(value) OVER (
    ORDER BY CAST (strftime('%s', date) AS INT)
    RANGE BETWEEN 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 PRECEDING
        AND 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 FOLLOWING
) AS MovingAverageWindow7
FROM t ORDER BY date;
```

Answer (score 6):

I think I actually found a solution :

```
SELECT date, value, 
  (SELECT AVG(value) FROM t t2 
   WHERE datetime(t1.date, '-3 days') <= datetime(t2.date) AND datetime(t1.date, '+3 days') >= datetime(t2.date)
   ) AS MAVG
FROM t t1
GROUP BY strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date);
```

[image]

I don't know if it is the most efficient way, but it seems to work

**Edit :** 
Applied to my real database containing 20 000 rows, a weekly moving average over two parameters takes approximately 1 minute to be calculated.

I see two options there :

- There is a more efficient way to compute this with SQLite
- I compute the moving average in Python after extracting data from SQLite

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to create a intermediate table that maps each date to the groups it belong to.

```sql
CREATE TABLE groups (date DATE, daygroup DATE);
INSERT INTO groups 
  SELECT date, strftime('%Y-%m-%d', datetime(date, '-1 days')) AS daygroup
  FROM t;  
INSERT INTO groups 
  SELECT date, strftime('%Y-%m-%d', datetime(date, '-2 days')) AS daygroup
  FROM t;  
INSERT INTO groups 
  SELECT date, strftime('%Y-%m-%d', datetime(date, '-3 days')) AS daygroup
  FROM t;  
INSERT INTO groups 
  SELECT date, strftime('%Y-%m-%d', datetime(date, '+1 days')) AS daygroup
  FROM t;  
INSERT INTO groups 
  SELECT date, strftime('%Y-%m-%d', datetime(date, '+2 days')) AS daygroup
  FROM t;  
INSERT INTO groups 
  SELECT date, strftime('%Y-%m-%d', datetime(date, '+3 days')) AS daygroup
  FROM t;  
INSERT INTO groups 
  SELECT date, date AS daygroup FROM t;
```

You get for example,

```
SELECT * FROM groups WHERE date = '2018-02-05'

    date        daygroup
    2018-02-05  2018-02-04
    2018-02-05  2018-02-03
    2018-02-05  2018-02-02
    2018-02-05  2018-02-06
    2018-02-05  2018-02-07
    2018-02-05  2018-02-08
    2018-02-05  2018-02-05
```

indicating that '2018-02-05' belongs to groups '2018-02-02' to '2018-02-08'.  If a date belongs to a group, then the value of the data joins the calculation of moving average for the group.

With this, calculating the moving average becomes straightforward:

```sql
SELECT
  d.date, d.value, c.ma
FROM
  t AS d
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT 
    b.daygroup,
    avg(a.value) AS ma
  FROM 
    t AS a 
  INNER JOIN
    groups AS b
  ON a.date = b.date
  GROUP BY b.daygroup) AS c
ON
  d.date = c.daygroup
```

Note that the number of rows of intermediate table is 7 times as large as that of original table, it grows proportionately as taking wider the window.  This should be acceptable unless you have much larger table.

I also experimented with 20 000 rows.
The insert query took 1.5s and select query took 0.5s on my laptop.

## ADDED, perhaps better.

An alternative that does not require intermediate table.
The query below merges the table with itself, in a way 3 days lag is allowed, then takes average.

```sql
SELECT
  t1.date, avg(t2.value) AS MVG
FROM 
  t AS t1
INNER JOIN
  t AS t2
ON
  datetime(t1.date, '-3 days') <= datetime(t2.date) 
  AND 
  datetime(t1.date, '+3 days') >= datetime(t2.date)
GROUP BY
  t1.date
;
```